# Drawing rectangles of different sizes in a loop

Tags: java, loops, processing, rectangles

I wrote this little snippet of code in Processing, that draws rectangles via a loop… each rectangle is slighty wider as the code loops through the rows… So far so good… But what I actually would like to achieve is that in the first row is 1 rectangle, in the second row 2, in the third 3 and so on… in other words, that every row has as many rectangles in it as its row number…
But I am really stuck here. I thought of a nested loop. With that I can draw in X and Y axis… but how to combine that with the with? Does this have something with fractals to do?

Here ist my little snippet:

```
 int rows = 100;

void setup() {
  size(1080, 1080);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  translate(0, height/rows/2);
  
  for (int y=0; y < rows; y ++) {
  rect(width/2, (height/rows)*y, width/rows*y, height/rows);
  }
  
}
```

Thank you for any kind of help!

All the best and thank you!
I added a picture that shows what I try to achieve:

[image: This is what I want to draw with the loop]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laancelot's solution is elegant(+1).

Here is a commented variation using nested for loops:

```
void setup() {
  size(1024, 512);
  
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(3);
  
  background(0);
  // number of rows: this should fill the screen, more will be hard to see
  int rows = 6;  
  // the initial height of a box 
  float boxHeight = height / 2;
  // the initial y position of the box
  float y = boxHeight;
  // the initial number of boxes
  int hCount = 2;
  
  // for each row
  for(int row = 0; row < rows; row++){
    
    // compute the width per box
    float boxWidth = width / hCount;
    
    // for each box per row
    for(int i = 0; i < hCount; i++){
      // draw the box, offset on X
      rect(boxWidth * i, y, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    }
    // increment values for next row...
    // half the height
    boxHeight /= 2;
    // move boxes lower
    y += boxHeight;
    // draw twice as many boxes on the next row
    hCount *= 2;
  }
  
}
```

[image: subdivided rectangles a-la Cantor Set]

You can run a demo bellow:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1024, 512);
  
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(3);
  
  background(0);
  // number of rows: this should fill the screen, more will be hard to see
  let rows = 6;  
  // the initial height of a box 
  let boxHeight = height / 2;
  // the initial y position of the box
  let y = boxHeight;
  // the initial number of boxes
  let hCount = 2;
  
  // for each row
  for(let row = 0; row < rows; row++){
    
    // compute the width per box
    let boxWidth = width / hCount;
    
    // for each box per row
    for(let i = 0; i < hCount; i++){
      // draw the box, offset on X
      rect(boxWidth * i, y, boxWidth, boxHeight);
    }
    // increment values for next row...
    // half the height
    boxHeight /= 2;
    // move boxes lower
    y += boxHeight;
    // draw twice as many boxes on the next row
    hCount *= 2;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

This seems related to a fractal, the [Cantor Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) in particular.

Comment: Hi George! Thank you too! Really appreciate it! I just found out I did something stupid… 
In my question I wanted to draw as many rectangles in a row as its row number – like row ONE, 1 Rectangle, row 2, Two Rectangles, row 3, THREE Retangles… But in my visual Explanation i did not do it this why – there I did it recursive… So i tried to change it with your code but could not figure it out :-(

Answer (score 3):

TIME FOR RECURSION!!!

Pardon my enthusiasm, but I love recursion and I don't have many opportunities to use it (mostly because it can be avoided most of the time and also because to use it at the wrong time is straight up moron).

The way I see this, you can achieve this with the following pseudocode:

```
Draw a rectangle
Draw 2 smaller rectangles underneath the last one
Use this logic on each of the smaller rectangles
```

Now, the MOST IMPORTANT THING with recursion is that you need an exit condition. Here, I suppose that you could input the number of "lines" that you want, or stop writing rectangles whenever they are too small to be seen as rectangles. Why not both? Let's write both:

[image: RECURSION! RECURSION! AT LAST!]

```
void setup() {
  size(800, 600);
  background(0);
  stroke(255);
  noFill();
  
  // drawing a couple lines of squares
  DrawRectangles(new PVector(0,0), 200, width, 6); // for 6 lines of rectangles
  // if you try it with a stupid number, like 600 iterations, it'll stop anyway when the rectangles are so small that they can't be seen
}

void draw() {}

void DrawRectangles(PVector position, int squareHeight, int squareWidth, int iterations) {
  // if you can draw more rectangles it'll continue, else it stops
  // a recursive method MUST have a stop condition, or else it becomes an infinite loop!
  if (squareHeight > 0 && iterations > 0) {
    // draw a rectangle and call this method twice for the next line
    rect(position.x, position.y, squareWidth, squareHeight);
    DrawRectangles(new PVector(position.x, position.y + squareHeight), (int)(squareHeight/2), (int)(squareWidth/2), iterations-1);
    DrawRectangles(new PVector(position.x + squareWidth/2, position.y + squareHeight), (int)(squareHeight/2), (int)(squareWidth/2), iterations-1); 
  }
}
```

That's the idea. There are MANY ways to do what you want, so other answers may be just as good as this one, but... I like this one. I'll hang around in case you have questions about this code in the comments.

Have fun!

Comment: Oops I forgot that you wanted to do this in a loop. I hope it doesn't matter, else let me know and I'll think about something else!

Comment: Yes this is it! PERFECT! Thank you very much! Also for explaining it to me so well – i really appreciate it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

+++EDIT+++

Here is the right visual sketch to what my question was about – my bad – your answers were totally correct to my first visual sketch and very helpful!

[image: right one]

I got quit near with this code right here but I could not yet manage to keep a first given ratio (of the first rectangle) and let them then shrink – like in my visual scribble above:

```
    int rows = 20;
float rectHeight;
float rectStep;
void setup() {
  size(1080, 1080);
  noFill();
  stroke(255);
  rectHeight = float(height)/rows;
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  for (int y=0; y < rows; y++) {
    rectStep = float(width)/(y+1);
    for(int x = 0; x <= y+1*2; x++){
      rect(x*rectStep, y*rectHeight, rectStep, rectHeight);
    }
  }
}
```

The factor by which they shrink from from first row down differs:
2, 1.5, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 1.0 and so on …

I have no clue whats the math behind it…
Does someone have an idea?

Thank you for any kind of help!

Comment: `float(width)/(y+1)` means that the width of a rectangle will be equal to the width of the screen divided by the "line number" where you currently are. That's why there's always one more rectangle on every line. It's dynamically calculated.

Comment: The rectangles are drawn in a loop inside a loop. The outer loop iterate "lines" and the inner loop draws rectangles, so if you're at the line #3 you're supposed to have 3 rectangles. At line 3 `rectStep` is `width / 3` so you can fit 3 rectangles in the line. The rectangle coordinates are `x * recstep` so they are side-by-side, that's why `recstep` has to be recalculated in the outer loop: the value differs on every line.

Comment: `rectHeight` is a little more tricky, because it doesn't work as shown in your image: in the code snippet, it's being calculated only once, so every line has the same height. For it to work like in the image, it would need to be dynamically calculated. The easiest way to do so would be to use 2 variables: one which is the "current y" and one which is the "current rectangle height". The current y would increase after every line by the amount of the rectangle height, and the rectangle height would be reduced by... about `* 0.75` i'd say, but it's up to you to set this up.

Comment: Little correction:  "so if you're at the line #3 you're supposed to have 4 rectangles. At line 3 rectStep is 'width / 3 + 1' so you can fit 4 rectangles in the line".

Comment: Hi Laancelot! Thank you so much for the explanation! I will check it out and let you know! All the best! Cyrill